# How to display virtual keyboard in ios6 Simulator

Tags: ios

How do you display the virtual keyboard in ios6 Simulator (iphone or iPad) ? I've tried the toggle keyboard option, but nothing appears, can you only make it appear with code? and if so, how?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can't show the keyboard without a 'target'. The system needs to know where it should send the entered text to.

So if you have a subclass of UIView that accepts text input (UITextField for example), the keyboard is either shown when the user taps that view or you can programmatically trigger it by calling:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

From [iOS-Documentation Managing the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html):

> Displaying the Keyboard
>
> When the user taps a view, the system automatically designates that view as the first responder. When this happens to a view that contains editable text, the view initiates an editing session for that text. At the beginning of that editing session, the view asks the system to display the keyboard, if it is not already visible. If the keyboard is already visible, the change in first responder causes text input from the keyboard to be redirected to the newly tapped view.
>
> Because the keyboard is displayed automatically when a view becomes the first responder, you often do not need to do anything to display it. However, you can programmatically display the keyboard for an editable text view by calling that view’s becomeFirstResponder method. Calling this method makes the target view the first responder and begins the editing process just as if the user had tapped on the view.
>
> If your application manages several text-based views on a single screen, it is a good idea to track which view is currently the first responder so that you can dismiss the keyboard later.